# Components does not render by Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to render my four components Cart, Home, Catalog, and Products in my Routes components. Oddly, only my home components is rendered out. I don't know what is wrong with my codes, hope i can get some help from you guys! Thank you so much! This is my codesanbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/ecommerce-r168p?file=/src/routes/Routes.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exact` props to solve your issue.

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/product" component={Product} />
        <Route exact path="/catalog" component={Catalog} />
        <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Or you can move the `home` route to bottom

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/product" component={Product} />
        <Route path="/catalog" component={Catalog} />
        <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Here you'll find the details https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route
Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/ecommerce-forked-vj9uz?file=/src/components/Layout.js

Comment: yah i tried both of your suggestions but it's not worrking still...

Comment: Please check this https://codesandbox.io/s/ecommerce-forked-vj9uz?file=/src/components/Layout.js